# scanf not reading mychars

Tags: c, pointers, memory, scanf, truncate

I'm making a visual display for pointers by using a table. The first input for `length` works but `mychars` is not being read. I know that there's a new line after `scanf` but I don't know how it behaves. How is `mychars`'s `scanf` parsed in my particular case?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int length;
    printf("Length? ");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    char *mychars = (char *)calloc(length, sizeof(char));

    printf("mychars? ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", mychars);
    printf("mychars is \"%s\"\n", mychars);
    printf("pointer at %p\n", mychars);
    if (strlen(mychars) == length) {
        printf("Address    Location        Value\n");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            printf("%-10p *(mychars+%02d) %3c\n", (mychars+i), i, *(mychars+i));
        }
    } else {
        print("Not right length");
    }
    free(mychars);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a variable "is not working"?

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you. Why does it work?

Comment: BTW: how do you check that `length` and the length of the input from `scanf(" %[^\n]s", mychars);` fit?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Should I include an extra `if`?

Comment: `%s` allows to add a field width, you can use that.

Comment: If you expect the string input to consist of `length` characters, then you are not allocating enough space: you need room for the terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `scanf()`.  It is evil.  It does not handle problems well and is easy for learners to mis-use.  Use `fgets()`.

```
// untested code
int main(void) {
  size_t length;  // Use size_t for array sizes
  printf("Length? ");
  fflush(stdout); // Insure prompt is displayed before input.

  char buf[50];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%zu", &length) != 1) return -1;

  char *mychars = malloc(length + 2);  // +1 for \n, +1 for \0
  if (mychars == NULL) return -1;

  printf("mychars? ");
  fflush(stdout);
  if (fgets(mychars, length + 2, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
  // lop off potential \n
  mychars[strcspn(mychars, "\n")] = 0;

  printf("mychars is \"%s\"\n", mychars);
  printf("pointer at %p\n", (void*) mychars);  // Use `void *` with %p

  if (strlen(mychars) == length) {
    printf("Address    Location        Value\n");
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      printf("%-10p *(mychars+%02zu) %3c\n", (void*) (mychars + i), i, *(mychars + i));
    }
  } else {
    printf("Not right length\n");  // add \n
  }
  free(mychars);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your high-level code and it doesn't run quite right. This is what I get:$ runc.py newstat
removing
"newstat.exe" deleted
compiling
Compiled!
Execution space
--------------------------------------------------
Length? 10

--------------------------------------------------
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @Clayton Wahlstrom 1) Step through the code.  2) Code is likely exiting on one of the `return -1;`  3) Suspect you are using a non-compliant C compiler that has trouble with `"%zu"` - change to `"%u"` and use type `unsigned` rather than `size_t`.

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom Well, [tested](https://ideone.com/VJ7Nr9) (you only have to add an `f` to the last `print(...`) and it "works" as expected.